# Exploding a string with different separators, Eg ( )

Tags: php

Is there a way to explode a string with different separators/delimiters, for example this string

```
code code code (1) code code@ (2) code code code (3) code (4)
```

The 2 is the number I want to get as the result, is there an easy way to do this with php?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you are using as delimiters. So you want to explode all of that just to get the number 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get the data inside of the parentheses, the following code will match that for you:

```
preg_match_all('/\((\d+)\)/', $str, $matches);
```

```
var_dump($matches[1][1]); // string(1) "2"
```

If you're trying to split the string using the delimiter of `(<some-number>)`, the code below will work for you:

```
$arr = preg_split('/\(\d+\)/', $str);
```

```
var_dump($arr[2]); // string(16) " code code code "
```